# How can I solve this "missing curly bracket" error in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started a project in Unity and created a basic third person controller script to start prototyping and I got this error in the console which says that I'm missing a curly bracket when clearly I'm not. Here I show you guys the code and the console error:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThirdPersonMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private CharacterController charController;
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 5f;

    void Update()
    {
        private float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        private float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        private Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

        if(direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            charController.Move(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }   
}
```

[Errors in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGp9I.png)

I don't really get why this happens, I tried reinstalling Visual Studio, regenerating the project files in the external tools tab, and after wacthing a lot of videos I still don't understand the error.

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code for your future posts. This one is clearly typo (it would be extremely rude to think you don't know that `private` can't be inside methods)...

Comment: I edited the post to show real [mre] - consider this as an example of what question should have contained (you can see the edit in the history as I reverted it - only original author is expected to edit code with a real example even if that action makes post easier to read/follow guidance).

Comment: Why are you trying to use `private` in a variable declaration? Variables aren't visible outside the method so they don't need access specifiers. Reinstalling Visual Studio won't fix a syntax error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessibility modifiers (`private`) can not be used in a method body because they can never be accessed externally, they are effectively always private.  Remove the `private` keyword.